# No schema in file database after running program persisted to hsqldb:file via hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

Here is hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:test_db_file</property>
    <property name="hsqldb.write_delay">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">combine1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <!--
         few resources
    -->

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I change hsqldb to mysql db, it works fine. But when I leave it like this, and I connect hsqldb:file as database in NetBeans, there is nothing in Public schema where I suppose to find created tables after running program.

During runtime, classes are persisted, I can load them from session etc., but after program ends, there is nothing. Except in test_db_file.script are queries to create desired schema, but not rows I saved into db.

Here is my simple main, as I wrote, when I use some mysql database, it works:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import resources.HibernateUtil;
import website.Website;

public class MrhAdministration {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    WebsiteCreator.create(session);

    Criteria criterial = session.createCriteria(Website.class);
    for (Website w : (List<Website>) criterial.list()) {
      System.out.println("Sites: " + w.getSiteName() + " " + w.getSiteUrl());
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();
  }
}
```

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is the location of the database files. You are using a relative path `jdbc:hsqldb:file:test_db_file` which resolves to different locations when you use different programs to access the database. Try an absolute path, for example `jdbc:hsqldb:file:/db/test_db_file`

Note your other settings for username and write_delay are valid for recent version 2.2.x and later. They won't work for version 1.8.x.

Comment: Thanks for reply, good point, but when I use absolute address for both, with same user credetials (I create database files via netbeans database connection, and then try to use it from program I got this: `java.sql.SQLException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@340e5f64[file =/home/myhome/tmp/mydb1/mydb1.lck` any idea? Somehow set permitions in mydb1.script?

Comment: You can access the database with ONE process at a time. The error shows the db is still kept open by the other Java process. If you want simultaneous access, run an an HSQLDB Server.