# persistence in hsqldb with spring

Tags: spring, persistence, hsqldb

I'm struggling with persistence with spring and hsqldb. I checked out several questions but couldn't manage to find a solution:

Threads checked out:
[No schema in file database after running program persisted to hsqldb:file via hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112966/no-schema-in-file-database-after-running-program-persisted-to-hsqldbfile-via-hi)
[HSQLDB and Hibernate/JPA - not persisting to disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551988/hsqldb-and-hibernate-jpa-not-persisting-to-disk)
[Hibernate doesn't save any records in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362009/hibernate-doesnt-save-any-records-in-database/10363558#10363558)

However this didn't help so far. Everytime I restart my webserver all changes are gone and nothing is written to my harddisk.

Hibernate configuration is as follows

```
@Bean
public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("hibernate.dialect", HSQLDialect.class.getName());
    props.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    props.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    props.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:hsqldb:file:c:\\temp\\rvec");
    props.put("hibernate.connection.username", "sa");
    props.put("hibernate.connection.password", "");
    props.put("hibernate.connection.pool_size","1");
    props.put("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "true");


    AnnotationSessionFactoryBean bean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
    bean.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class[]{Course.class, User.class, Event.class});       
    bean.setHibernateProperties(props);

    bean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    bean.setSchemaUpdate(true);
    return bean;
}
```

data source and transaction manager are configured in servlet-context.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

There are no errors thrown in the console but only valid sql statements.
Any ideas?

Kind regards, 
Lomu

Comment: Maybe it's because of the embedded-data source I use in the servlet-context (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch12s08.html)

Comment: Yes, it was because I configured a embedded-data source instead of a "normal" datasource in the bean configuration. what a stupid mistake :)